# IDLE won't highlight my syntax

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, python-idle

Using IDLE and Python version 2.7.3. Only when I start a new file it highlights for a few lines and then just stops after I press F5. So all my text becomes plain black.

If there are equally good/better  command line and editor combinations out there, you may always suggest them.

Comment: I have the same problem both under Windows 7 AND MacOSX, on different computers! Baffling really...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This happened to me too. Save it as .py (manually type .py in the document name), and the highlighting will come back.

Comment: I also experienced the same thing with 2.7.9 and this was the correct answer for me.

Comment: Noted and changed (albeit 3 years later...)

Answer (score 7):

Check the key binding for the **toggle-auto-coloring** option under **Options** -> **Configure IDLE** -> **Keys** -> **Custom Key Bindings**. The default is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. This should allow you to turn the syntax highlighting back on. (You can't toggle it off though, heh)

Works for me on both IDLE 2.7 and IDLE 3.3.3.

Comment: @sterling Feel free to edit answers to add useful info.

Answer (score 6):

I usually have to save the file as .py before IDLE will do any syntax highlighting at all.  Not sure why it would highlight for a few and then stop though.  I've never had that happen.

Answer (score 2):

Is this under Windows? Is it possible your file association for Python files have possibly changed? (not quite sure why/how this could happen, but perhaps something worth checking)

Comment: Well it doesn't have any association at all now. Which application should I use in my C:\Pyhon27\ folder?

Comment: @PatronBernard can you try python.exe - that's what I have with Windows 7 - it's a long shot, but perhaps it will help. It is odd, because most tools will just look at the .py file extension to activate the syntax highlighting.

Comment: @PatronBernard Here are some links for alternative Python editors:
http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonEditors and this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126753/is-there-a-good-free-python-ide-for-windows
Hope this helps

Comment: I am now using PyDev and Eclipse. Works like a charm!